Based on a Google Form Submitter's name, create a folder, rename the files and relocate those files to that created folder
I am trying to create a Google Apps Script that allows me to do the following.
My Google Form looks like this:

What is your company name.
Submitt your company logo.
Submitt your company photo.
Submitt your company video.

When a response is recorded, I wanted the files submitted through questions 2-4 to be renamed to the response in 1 (company name) (e.g. CompanyName_Logo, CompanyName_Photo, CompanyName_Video).
Then I wanted a folder to be created in a parent folder in GDrive. The created folder will be named after CompanyName.
Then I wanted all the files submitted to be relocated to this folder.
But I realised the submittor may want to submit more than one file for each question.
A very helpful stack overflow responder provided me this code below. But I realized the code is only suitable when only one file is submitted per question. How do I modify this code to allow more than one file submitted per question can be processed? :
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const responses = e.values;
  const companyName = responses[1]; 
  const logoFileId = extractFileId(responses[2]); 
  const photoFileId = extractFileId(responses[3]); 
  const videoFileId = extractFileId(responses[4]);
  
  const parentFolderId = 'paste-parent-folder-id-here'; 
  const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);
  const companyFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(companyName);
  
  function moveAndRenameFile(fileId, newName) {
    try {
      if (fileId) {
        Logger.log(`Attempting to move file ID: ${fileId}`);
        const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
        file.setName(newName);
        file.moveTo(companyFolder);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.log(`Error with file ID ${fileId}: ${error.message}`);
    }
  }

  moveAndRenameFile(logoFileId, `${companyName}_Logo`);
  moveAndRenameFile(photoFileId, `${companyName}_Photo`);
  moveAndRenameFile(videoFileId, `${companyName}_Video`);
}

function extractFileId(url) {
  if (url) {
    const parts = url.split('=');
    return parts.length > 1 ? parts[1] : null;
  }
  return null;
}


This post is not a good fit for this site as it's not a service desk. Please [edit] the post to make it about a specific problem unique to programming. Most of these questions include a [mcve] focused on a single task to be done by the code.

Move Multiple Files on FormSubmit
I modified your code this can now handle and move multiple files on formsubmit.
Here's the code:
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  const responses = e.values;
  const companyName = responses[1];
  const logoFileId = responses[2];
  const photoFileId = responses[3];
  const videoFileId = responses[4];

  const parentFolderId = 'paste-parent-folder-id-here';
  const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);
  const companyFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(companyName);

  extractFileId(logoFileId, `${companyName}_Logo`);
  extractFileId(photoFileId, `${companyName}_Photo`);
  extractFileId(videoFileId, `${companyName}_Video`);

  function extractFileId(url, name) {
    const data = url;
    if (data.includes(',')) {
      const splitedData = data.split(',');
      for (let i = 0; i < splitedData.length; i++) {
        moveAndRenameFile(splitedData[i].split("=")[1], name)
      }
      return
    } else if (!data) {
      console.log("No Action taken");
      return;
    }
    moveAndRenameFile(data.split("=")[1], name)
    return
  }


  function moveAndRenameFile(fileId, newName) {
    try {
      if (fileId) {
        Logger.log(`Attempting to move file ID: ${fileId}`);
        const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
        file.setName(newName);
        file.moveTo(companyFolder);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.log(`Error with file ID ${fileId}: ${error.message}`);
    }
  }

}


Here is how you create a form question with attach multiple files.

Sample Output




References:

For Loop

JavaScript String Reference


